# Understanding intents for android through AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, android-intent

Im just trying to do something for android using AS3 and I can't make it works.

Im trying to call an intent through an internal url. i.e. in my app I want to call myapp://com.android.myapp and that should be calling a specific intent.

This is the intent defined on the manifest:

```
      <receiver android:name="com.myapp.CustomReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="com.android.myapp"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
```

I already have CustomReceiver declared with onReceive function.

And then on AS3 Im trying to call the url through

```
      navigateToUrl(new URLRequest("myapp://com.android.myapp"));
```

But the intent is never called, can you help me to understand what can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter> 
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> 
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
   <data android:scheme="myapp"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

Source:http://dreamingwell.com/articles/archives/2011/06/flex-mobile-cus-2.php

Comment: I tried but is not working neither. Im not sure if I have some usefull data on the log. I see some lines from "ApplicationPolicy" saying "IsIntentDisabled resolve info :null" and then "IsIntentDisabled return :false"

Comment: Long time ago I found a post describing, that many phones convert "myapp://com.android.myapp" to "http://myapp.com..." by default. Maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: I noticed that the example doesn't use a receiver, I assume that it receive the call through the main activity, right?

Comment: That's a good point, I always tried with the same phone, Im going to check that

Comment: You are right. From the google documentation: `An Intent object is passed to Context.startActivity() or Activity.startActivityForResult() to launch an activity or get an existing activity to do something new. (It can also be passed to Activity.setResult() to return information to the activity that called startActivityForResult().)` Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: What I see is that Context.startActivity() is something that you have to do if you want to open the app when the receiver get the message. But my problem is that the receiver is never called :(